# erlang httpc sending http response to wrong handler

Tags: erlang

Our app makes a lot of HTTP requests and we are facing this issue with both inets-5.5.1 and 5.3.2.

Basically our receive clause for the response is trying to match the request id returned in httpc:request call
and we see that the Request Id match fails

We gave seen this mismatch in all 3 receive clauses for
stream_start, stream and stream_end

What we observed after a lot of trial and error  is that if the same pid makes  the http requests, the responses get kind of muddled up but if we spawn a separate process for the httpc:request,  it is better . We also tried using a separate httpc profile to isolate the current process requests  from other process requests. But even after this we have seen a lot of occurrences of this faulty behavior.

This is occurring with a lot of our http requests.  Has anyone faced this ?

Thanks
Suma

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a direct solution, but....

I suggest you try a much more "heavy duty" http client called **[ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse/wiki/ibrowse-API)**.

(if it is not too late for your project!)

Inets httpd and httpc are better for "simple HTTP tasks", so you may need **[Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org)**, **[Mochiweb](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/)** e.t.c if you need to do "duty grade" HTTP jobs instead of inets httpd

wish u success!